# pandas Dataframe Concat/Upsert on a Combination Key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet

Let's say I have the following dataset

```
ID | Name | balance | Year
112 Johnstown $321 2020
321 Oregon $214 2020
121 Jackson $254 2020
```

and the following incoming dataset

```
112 Johnstown $321 2021
321 Oregon $216 2020
121 Jackson $254 2020
```

What I want to do is combine these two datasets while retaining a concept of seasonality. Basically, if a record has any field other than the year changed, update that record. However, if the record had the year changed, then make a new record.

So in our case, the result dataset would look like this

```
112 Johnstown $321 2021
112 Johnstown $321 2020
321 Oregon $216 2020
121 Jackson $254 2020
```

This is essentially an upsert operation, the way I'm thinking about it is as an upsert on a combination key of ID and season. Basically, if the ID and season are the same update the existing record, and if they're different add a new record. In other words

1. If a record is exactly the same do nothing
2. If a record is different but year/id are the same take the record
   from the new dataset

3.If a record is different and year/id are
different make a new record

Is this possible with dataframes? If not, is there another structure I should look at for implementing this? Our datasets are just parquet files, so we're free to manipulate them however we like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this expected output? Based on your

> Basically, if the ID and season are the same update the existing
> record, and if they're different add a new record.

We concatenate two dataframes, group by `ID` and `Year` and leave the last (thus, coming from `df2`) element in each group.

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(["ID", "Year"], as_index=False).last()
    ID  Year       Name balance
0  112  2020  Johnstown    $321
1  112  2021  Johnstown    $321
2  121  2020    Jackson    $254
3  321  2020     Oregon    $216
```

Comment: I think you've got it. Yes, the idea here is basically that I have an existing dataset and a new dataset. I want to combine the two datasets with the following logic

1. If a record is exactly the same do nothing 

2. If a record is different but year/id are the same take the record from the new dataset

3.If a record is different and year/id are different make a new record

Comment: Hey crayxt, it didn't seem to work. I'm generating the dataframe like this

outputDF = pd.concat([z2DF, z1DF]).groupby(["ID", "year"], as_index=False).last()

I know the z1DF has newer information in it, but the result dataframe I get is exactly the same as what was in z2DF at the start.

Comment: Note that my dataframes actually have 15 or so columns, not sure if that could impact it. I have no clue why nothing is changing, there are non group-by changes in df1 that should be reflected

Comment: Got it working! Messed up how I was sourcing the data, thank you again!